# Connection string causes Login failed for user when creating a table but not when creating a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, ado.net

I have been able to create a new database with this connection string:

```
 SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=True;User Instance=True");
```

But when I use this connection string to create a Table:

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database='FormsDB';Integrated security=True;User Instance=True");
```

It gives me a login fail for user

I tried so far :

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog='FormsDB';Integrated security=True;User Instance=True;Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

and I am getting the same error message:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "FormsDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'LC-SURF\Tums'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at .....
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: issue is the login doesn't have permission on that database. its a valid login with no permission for that database

Comment: it looks like you have rights to create a database, but no rights to create a table. Just try with other credentials. If it is your own local database for developing, try with `sa` login.

Comment: Permission issues aren't related to the *connection string*, they are related to the *account*. Add the proper permissions to your account, or ask whoever installed the database and has administrator permissions, to do so. By default the user who installs SQL Server Express is also an administrator

Comment: check the permissions on the database for the windows account running the application and make sure it has read/write permissions on the database.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am using Visual Studio locally. How do I find out what is the sa password? I have never setup a password for this database since I have just created it right before trying to create the table. I installed SQL Server Express on my computer and am just using windows authentication. How do I check the permissions on the database for the windows account? I am really lost here.

Comment: @user1468225 read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669065(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337552.aspx and the related links.   You don't need to use the SA account.

Answer (score -2):

Connection string like this format, and you have to login your SQL Server with sa account.

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = FormsDB;Integrated Security = True; User Id = sa; Password = sql";
```

Comment: and then pass this variable into a 
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

Comment: You can't have both Integrated Security (ie use the application's Windows account) *and* SQL Server security (Username/Password). Besides, giving `sa` access to everyone is a *bad* idea.

Comment: Most of the issue cause due to login database with Windows Authentication. May be client has access remote database.

Comment: Actually, Windows Authentication is *not* a problem, it's a *very good* security feature - no passwords to leak, no need for sweeping config changes to change the password. If there are access restrictions, the OP should fix them, not open the database to anyone who can read the config file

Comment: this answer is nonsensical on 3 levels - 1. setting integrated security to true, yet providing username and password. 2. using the SA account details in plaintext. 3. The comment " you have to login your SQL Server with sa account" is not true.